# Unable to construct 4-state NFA for certain regular expression

Tags: regex, automata, nfa, non-deterministic

In an exercise on NFA's I'm asked to construct a 4-state NFA on the regular expression (aa|aab)*b.
I have tried to construct it myself, and I could only find a 5-state NFA, which an online tool later confirmed.
[image: NFA]

(I found it without (4) being final and an additional arrow from (3) to (2) of b, but this results in the same) Is it me failing to see a problem, or isn't there a way to do this with just four states?

Comment: If (4) wouldn't be final, your nfa wouldn't match `aab` as opposed to the one you've shown?

Comment: You're absolutely right, I now see that in my own sketch I have an arrow (b) from (3) to (2) as well

Comment: Which tool have you used? I might be able to create a picture with my solution then.

Comment: It's this tool: http://hackingoff.com/compilers/regular-expression-to-nfa-dfa You can only insert the regular expression, and it will calculate a possible NFA/DFA for you, so I'm afraid you can't use it to construct an NFA yourself. Your solution however works great!

Comment: He, but http://hackingoff.com/compilers/nfa-to-dfa-conversion does accept arbitrary NFAs in JSON format :-)

Comment: You need another more state, when you are in state 1, and receive a b, you must jump to a error state in which whatever you receive you get stuck there.  So you need six states, not five. This is the case in you receive for example the string "ab".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've chosen to create a DFA (and I can't tell how to make one with only 4 states either). However, you are allowed to build an [NFA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_finite_automaton), which means you can have multiple transitions with the same letter.

You could therefore omit state (2), move the `b`-edge that went from (0) to (2) onto (4), and introduce a new edge with the letter `b` from (3) to (0). This means that when reading a `b` after two `a`s, you can either transition to the final state or back to the beginning.

[image]

Comment: Ah thanks a lot! In my head I had switched to DFA's because at first I had found an NFA with 7 states, so I'd forgotten all about them..